# insert section into XML to balance a sum to 0

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML which is an accounting journal that must balance to 0.
What I want to achieve is that if it is not balancing by 1 unit (ONE unit), the XLST must insert a new line with 1 unit, and subsequent line number.

Source XML:

```
<ProcessSourceSystemJournalEntry xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" languageCode="en-US" systemEnvironmentCode="Production" versionID="9.2" releaseID="2.5.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2 http://schema.infor.com/Trunk/InforOAGIS/BODs/Developer/ProcessSourceSystemJournalEntry.xsd">
    <DataArea>
        <SourceSystemJournalEntry>
            <JournalEntryLine sequence="1">
                <Amount currencyID="XOF">10</Amount>
                <DebitCreditFlag>DEBIT</DebitCreditFlag>
            </JournalEntryLine>
            <JournalEntryLine sequence="2">
                <Amount currencyID="XOF">11</Amount>
                <DebitCreditFlag>CREDIT</DebitCreditFlag>
            </JournalEntryLine>
        </SourceSystemJournalEntry>
    </DataArea>
</ProcessSourceSystemJournalEntry>
```

Desired Output: The line number assigned is 3, the Amount can be hard-coded to 1 unit, and the DebitCreditFlag must be either DEBIT or CREDIT, so that total debits equal total credits.

```
<ProcessSourceSystemJournalEntry xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" languageCode="en-US" systemEnvironmentCode="Production" versionID="9.2" releaseID="2.5.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2 http://schema.infor.com/Trunk/InforOAGIS/BODs/Developer/ProcessSourceSystemJournalEntry.xsd">
    <DataArea>
        <SourceSystemJournalEntry>
            <JournalEntryLine sequence="1">
                <Amount currencyID="XOF">10</Amount>
                <DebitCreditFlag>DEBIT</DebitCreditFlag>
            </JournalEntryLine>
            <JournalEntryLine sequence="2">
                <Amount currencyID="XOF">11</Amount>
                <DebitCreditFlag>CREDIT</DebitCreditFlag>
            </JournalEntryLine>
            <JournalEntryLine sequence="3">
                <Amount currencyID="XOF">1</Amount>
                <DebitCreditFlag>DEBIT</DebitCreditFlag>
            </JournalEntryLine>
        </SourceSystemJournalEntry>
    </DataArea>
</ProcessSourceSystemJournalEntry>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: And where exactly is your attempted XSLT?